# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found. Code igniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, webserver, hosting

i have developed a web app on code igniter .. this is the first time i am working on code-igniter .. after developing a web application on my localhost .so i decided to put my code-igniter web app on the temporary free server.. so i uploaded my site on this site 
[1freehosting](http://www.1freehosting.com/)... and then i imported my database .. after that i have changed the settings of database in database.php file .. and also i changed the base url in config.php file ..as this is my domain name http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/... so i changed it to this url .. but then i am getting a following error ... i dont know what is going wrong ..i have searched a lot but nothing helps.. and also i am forgot to mention that my .htaccess file is empty ..means there is not a single line in it

this is the error i am getting

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

routes.php

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 $route['default_controller'] = "loginController";
$route['404_override'] = '';


 /* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

my controller

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class LoginController extends CI_Controller {

```
 function index(){

    $new['main_content'] = 'loginView';
    $this->load->view('loginTemplate/template', $new); 

}




function verifyUser(){

    //getting parameters from view 
    $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
    );


    $this->load->model('loginModel'); 
    $query = $this->loginModel->validate($data);


          if ($query){             //if the user c validated
        //data variable is created becx we want to put username in session
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                 'is_logged_in' => true 
            );

           $this->session->set_userdata($data);
         redirect('sessionController/dashboard_area');
    }
    else
     {
        $this->index();
    }
}
function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->index();
}
}



?>
```

config file

```
   $config['base_url']  = 'http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/';
   $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not have any .htaccess to edit you url you must add an `index.php`
when calling a controller like

`http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/index.php/loginController`

I tried accessing it via the url above and it works, but the database connection is not set up properly

in your config file where there is `$config['index_page'] = ''` if it is blank add an `index.php` to it

Check to see it works

Comment: thanks yaa it works .. thanks ..can you tell what should i do to access it through this url http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com   and i let u know that my config[index_page] is not blank ...

Comment: @mynameisjohn http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/ this is a topic to handle .htaccess problems with codeigniter

Comment: for more than a hundred decades for searching, I finally found the right answer. thanks men

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `application/routes.php` and make sure that your `$route['default_controller']` is correctly set to your default controller. As follows, this is my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Also, make sure that your default controller (in my case, its `application/controllers/home_controller.php` and within it is `class Home extends CI_Controller {...}`

--

If that doesn't work, make sure your default controller is correctly calling your default view and loading it as such:

```
$this->load->view('home_view', $data);
```

--

If THAT doesn't work, then take a look at your `application/config/config.php` and make sure that the following are correctly set as follows IF you want to get rid of your `index.php` in the url (for clean urls):

$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";

and if you're going for clean urls, do post your .htaccess (which should follow something like this: http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) so we can look at it in further detail and try to fix it if none of the above fix it.

Comment: The good thing is that your http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/license.txt is showing correctly. But I'm guessing you haven't modded your .htaccess since http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/license does not work.

Comment: thanks for your help ... look if there is any thing problem in my controllers or there is a problem that i am not loading view right then surely it can give me the error on localhost .. but it successfully works ...and for the htaccess file ..i have my htaccess file in the application folder .. and there is nothing in there .. i mean it is blank empty .. dont know what to write in there

Comment: @mynameisjohn can you post your default controller, routes.php and default view code please so we can take a look? It's returning a 404 because the routing is not finding something...

Comment: jsanc623 i updated my question ..

Comment: well if that is the case then i think it should not work in the first place .. as it works in localhost .. well i have matched the case but again .. nothing works .. giving me the same error

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment after checking case on my own CI. Can you post the upper bits of your config.php? The ones I mentioned above ($config['index_page']

Comment: i  have updated ..you can check ..

Comment: Have you tried leaving $config['base_url'] blank as `$config['base_url']  = '';` to see if that fixes it?

Comment: nope i didnt ... let me try it

Comment: Does 'sessionController/dashboard_area' exist? Because hitting http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/application/views/sessionController/dashboard_area.php gives me a 404

Comment: yeah it is .. i dont think so there is any problem of missing any files.. as i have build complete web app on my localhost ..and it is working successfully there but dont know why its not working on online server

Comment: i dont know  why it is giving this error .. as dashboard area is a function ..and in that function i am loading my view page

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed index.php with .htaccess?  If not then put it in the end.

Comment: i didnt get you ...my htaccess file is empty ... and yes an index.php file is present on the root