# codeigniter website showing 404 errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am getting 404 error while trying to my application on server. Its running perfectly on localhost. can anyone help me?
website url is: [Here is my site](http://vakratundasystem.in/application/kwikdeals/)
**Here is my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "HomeController";
```

Comment: Try to verify there is not another parent `.htaccess` overwriting your CodeIgniter one.. Hard question to answer really, are there any logs server side ??
Also can you reach http://vakratundasystem.in/application/kwikdeals/LoginController/login ?

Comment: A few good suggestions are in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591581/404-page-not-found-the-page-you-requested-was-not-found-code-igniter

Comment: yes i can access the controller directly but when i tried to access with only application name then got 404 error.

Comment: if you hosted you website to windows server, it might not provide use of .htaccess

Comment: but i removed index.php from url to make it seo friendly.

Comment: website is hosted on linux server.

Comment: Options -Multiviews
I use this  on Linux -- try it  out  : Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.phpbots\.txt|favicon\.ico|Classes|Examples)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Also  are you sure  your DNS is setup Properly  ??

Comment: still not working @jai
DNS settings are fine.

Comment: i am sorry there is an error in Rewrite Cond above  it should  be RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt) ---  Please replace that with this

Comment: i have already this line also in .htaccess file @jai

Comment: you site is working now

Comment: no still not wirking.

Comment: is it http://vakratundasystem.in/

Comment: yes . it is vakratundasystem.in

Comment: its still not working...

Comment: are you trying to access a controller  using this path =>application/kwikdeals

Comment: when i tried to access directly using http://vakratundasystem.in/application/kwikdeals/LoginController then it works fine but when i tried to access http://vakratundasystem.in/application/kwikdeals then it gives 404 error. in proxy link also

Comment: is kwikdeals => controller  ?  and LoginController => Method in kwikdeals controller right ?

Comment: no kwikdeals is the application and LoginController is the controller

Comment: .htaccess in kwikdeals  should  have  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kwikdeals/index.php?/$1 [PT,L]   where kwikdeals is folder name

Comment: Please Provide -> you app structure from Root folder

Comment: Still not working when i use your code...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kwikdeals/index.php?/$1 [PT,L]

Comment: public_html/application/kwikdeals

Comment: https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/287529/f1cuema4murLfmy85NFiKw4qmyi7ts3c/

Comment: is there a  kwikdeals folder ?  and is this the URL you are trying to access http://vakratundasystem.in/application/kwikdeals

Comment: yes. this is the same url i am trying to access

Comment: ok I dont think  its a problem with Htaccess  as it shows 404 Error Page ...its Something to do default controller

Comment: try adding an Index(){ var_dump("show ");} -- in default controller  and see if its hitting that

Comment: Thanks. Its has been resolved... Thank you very much.

Comment: how id  you solve it  ?if  you Dont Mind

Comment: sorry it was my mistake to give controller filename as capital letter like HomeController... first i generate log file then i see that log file in that it was converted into "homecontroller". After then i realize that codeigniter replace capital letter to small letter in all controllers and models file... Thanks... And sorry for my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have name your file and controller first letter in uppercase.
this may be issue on server side because linux is case sensitive.